# MySQL / BigQuery - Weighted Average & Group By

Tags: mysql, subquery, weighted-average

I am trying to calculate a **weighted average** of a dataset and return the **maximum value**, **monthly** over a period of 12 months along with its' corrosponding **ticket description**.

I'm aware that there are tons of questions out there addressing similar problems, but I have yet to find a solution that combines the syntaxes I believe are required.

Here's some sample table data:

| Month_Begin_Date | Priority | ticket_about_tag | Phone_Time | Occurances |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | Urgent | Power Bill | 22.42 | 36 |
| 2019-02-01 | Normal | Power Bill | 3.41 | 89 |
| 2019-05-01 | Normal | Wifi Issue | 45.32 | 12 |

Here's my current query for determining the weighted average:

```sql
SELECT (Month_Begin_Date, 
(sum(phone_time * occurances))/sum(occurances)) AS Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM database
GROUP BY month_begin_date
```

This returns the **weighted average** total for all ticket_about_tags, **monthly**.

But I still need to get this so that it displays the **maximum** **weighted average** grouped by **ticket description**. I.e. something that looks like this:

| Month_Begin_Date | ticket_about_tag | Weighted_average_phone_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | Power Bill | 22.42 |
| 2019-02-01 | Power Bill | 3.41 |
| 2019-03-01 | Wifi Issue | 45.32 |

I've tried adding this as a subquery into another query in order to return the data I'm after, like so:

```SQL
SELECT Month_Begin_date, Ticket_About_Tag, Phone_Average_Handle_Time 
FROM database WHERE CONCAT(month_begin_date,phone_time) IN 
(SELECT CONCAT (Month_Begin_Date, 
(sum(phone_time * occurances))/sum(occurances)) AS Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM database
GROUP BY month_begin_date
)
ORDER BY month_begin_date ASC
```

Thanks very much for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I got your question right, but using the following data:

| Month_Begin_Date | Priority | Ticket_About_Tag | Phone_Time | Occurences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | Urgent | Power Bill | 22.42 | 36 |
| 2019-02-01 | Normal | Power Bill | 3.41 | 89 |
| 2019-05-01 | Normal | Wifi Issue | 45.32 | 12 |
| 2019-02-01 | Urgent | Wifi Issue | 14.2 | 7 |
| 2019-02-01 | Normal | Wifi Issue | 30.7 | 5 |

Is this the query you're after?

```sql
SELECT 
Month_Begin_Date, Ticket_About_Tag,
SUM(Phone_Time * Occurences) / SUM(Occurences) AS Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM `database`
GROUP BY Month_Begin_Date, Ticket_About_Tag
ORDER BY Month_Begin_Date ASC, Ticket_About_Tag ASC;
```

That gives you a result like the one you posted:

| Month_Begin_Date | Ticket_About_Tag | Weighted_Average_Phone_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | Power Bill | 8.884880083084106 |
| 2019-02-01 | Wifi Issue | 21.075000206629436 |
| 2019-05-01 | Wifi Issue | 45.31999969482422 |

**Response to your comment**

To answer your comment you could:

```sql
SELECT
a.Month_Begin_Date, 
a.Ticket_About_Tag, 
b.Max_Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM (

SELECT 
Month_Begin_Date,
Ticket_About_Tag,
SUM(Phone_Time * Occurences) / SUM(Occurences) AS Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM `database`
GROUP BY Month_Begin_Date, Ticket_About_Tag

) a

LEFT JOIN (

SELECT
b1.Month_Begin_Date, 
MAX(b1.Weighted_Average_Phone_Time) AS Max_Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM (

SELECT 
Month_Begin_Date,
Ticket_About_Tag,
SUM(Phone_Time * Occurences) / SUM(Occurences) AS Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
FROM `database`
GROUP BY Month_Begin_Date, Ticket_About_Tag

) b1

GROUP BY b1.Month_Begin_Date

) b ON a.Month_Begin_Date = b.Month_Begin_Date

WHERE a.Weighted_Average_Phone_Time = b.Max_Weighted_Average_Phone_Time
```

That gives you the following output:

| Month_Begin_Date | Ticket_About_Tag | Max_Weighted_Average_Phone_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-01 | Wifi Issue | 21.075000206629436 |
| 2019-05-01 | Wifi Issue | 45.31999969482422 |

There are other ways of doing this, but I think this is by far the easiest way to understand without using other SQL constructs. It reflects your need of going through the same data twice, first to aggregate by month and ticket tag, then to find the maximum of the aggregate data by month.

Comment: That's perfect - thank you. Would there be a way to display the maximum Weighted Average Handle time per month? I.e. Twelve rows only (with the Ticket_About_Tag still shown alongside each max value).

Comment: I've edited the answer based on your comment. Cheers